# Surjective mapping from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to the set of symmetric positive (semi-)definite matrices of size $n\times n$

Tags: analytic-geometry, positive-definite

I want to map from $\mathbb{R}^m$ (for $m=n\cdot (n+1) / 2$, however, if another $m$ is necessary, that would also be ok) to symmetric positive (semi-)definite matrices.

I know that I can obtain a random positive semi-definite matrix by multiplying a random matrix by its transpose.
However, I assume that there are positive semi-definite matrices that cannot be produced by this procedure.
That is why I am looking for a subjective mapping to the space of symmetric positive (semi-)definite matrices of a given size.

I am aware that one could use a recursive function that checks whether the input is a symmetric positive (semi-)definite matrix and, if it is not tries some pseudo-random number in order to just check again until it finds one that is a symmetric positive (semi-)definite matrix.
However, I want to find a "nice" mapping that can produce all symmetric positive (semi-)definite matrices and is also a.e. differentiable.

Comment: "However, I assume that there are positive semi-definite matrices that cannot be produced by this procedure." There aren't, every PSD matrix has a unique positive square root which, multiplied by it's transpose (which is itself), would give you back that matrix.

Comment: @Rammus Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $l:\mathbb{R}^{{1 \over 2}n (n+1)} \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ to be a lower triangular matrix in the obvious way. Then $f(x)=l(x) l(x)^T$ is a surjective map onto the positive semidefinite matrices.

Comment: Why the down vote?